# problem with Double.ToString Method

Tags: c#, tostring

I am using this:

```
dSize.ToString("#.#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Where `dSize` is a `double`. it works fine when `dSize` is something like `2.5` **BUT** if `dSize` is something like `3` - so it does not have decimal part - it is returning `"3"` which is wrong. I want it to return `"3.0"`  so still with one decimal point.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `0` to indicate that the digit should be printed even if it is zero:

```
dSize.ToString("#.0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

This will print `.3` instead of `0.3`; if you want the digit before the decimal point to be printed too, use a `0` there as well:

```
dSize.ToString("0.0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
dSize.ToString("#.0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

`#` is a digit placeholder and will be printed if there is a digit in the number in that position.

`0` is a digit placeholder that will print the digit if there is one, or zero if there is no number in that position.

Reference: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as well as [Custom Number Format Strings Output Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x5bacwt%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Those should prove useful in conjunction with the answer that @Timwi provided.